# Trigger viewWillAppear when using a transitioning delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to present a view controller:

- Modally
- Using custom transitions
- At the same time, I want to make sure that when it is dismissed, *the view controller behind it is aware of being pushed to the foreground*.

My basic idea is to try some different configurations and see which one will lead to `viewWillAppear` being called on the view controller behind.

**Attempt 1**

```
presentedViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
presentedViewController.transitioningDelegate = someTransitioningDelegate
```

The results of this approach:

- The custom transition works perfectly well
- `viewWillAppear` does **not** get called on the view controller behind `presentedViewController` when I call `presentedViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true)`

I do want `viewWillAppear` to be called on the view controller below the one being dismissed, so I did this:

**Attempt 2**

```
presentedViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
presentedViewController.transitioningDelegate = someTransitioningDelegate
```

or

```
presentedViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
presentedViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .CoverVertical
presentedViewController.transitioningDelegate = someTransitioningDelegate
```

The results of this approach:

- `viewWillAppear` gets called on the view controller behind `presentedViewController` when dismissing `presentedViewController`
- The transition occurs as expected when *presenting* the view controller.
- When *dismissing* the view controller, the background during the transition is **black**, which is undesirable.

Seems that `.FullScreen` causes the view controllers behind `presentedViewController` to be removed from the display hierarchy - which is good because presumably that's what triggers the `viewWillAppear` call.

**Attempt 3**

```
presentedViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
presentedViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .CoverVertical
```

The results of this are:

- `viewWillAppear` gets called on the view controller behind `presentedViewController`.
- The background during the transition is the view controller located behind `presentedViewController`, which is desired.
- No custom transition.

---

The project I'm working on is structured in a way that makes it difficult to use delegation (which seems to be the suggested answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36786242/1111252)). Making use of `NSNotificationCenter` is another alternative which lets me call the code that is supposed to be called by `viewWillAppear`, but from attempt 3, I'm hoping there is a more elegant approach to achieve all these:

1. Trigger `viewWillAppear`
2. Use a custom transition
3. See the view controller being presented in the background during the transition animation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems Apple considers it foul play to invoke `viewWillAppear` etc., but it's okay to invoke `beginAppearanceTransition` and `endAppearanceTransition`, [which in turn will invoke `viewWillAppear`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29041911/1111252). I'm going with this.

Answer (score -1):

The way I have achieved this in the past is by calling viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear from the transition animator. Here's a simplified example:

```
public func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    let fromVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)
    let toVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)

    fromVC.viewWillDisappear(true)
    toVC.viewWillAppear(true)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {

            //Animations here

            }, completion: { (success) in
                toVC.viewDidAppear(success)
                fromVC.viewDidDisappear(success)
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })

}
```

I call the "will" methods before I do animations, and the "did" methods after completion