# Make custom interactive UIViewController dismissal call relevant view appearance methods

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am displaying a modal `UIViewController` on top of another. If the requisite `UIPanGestureRecognizer` triggers, I have an interactive `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` which basically pulls the modal view down to eventually dismiss it.

I notice that the view controller beneath does not receive any of the usual appearance methods when typically presenting and dismissing view controllers:
`-viewWillAppear:`,`-viewWillDisappear`, etc.

Is there any way, considering that this is an Apple-provided view controller API, to have these methods still be called at the appropriate times during the interaction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom transition animation not calling VC lifecycle methods on dismiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488267/custom-transition-animation-not-calling-vc-lifecycle-methods-on-dismiss)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you're calling `transitionContext.completeTransition` within your custom transition class which handles all the animations and gestures.
2. It may depend on the type of [`UIModalPresentationStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621355-modalpresentationstyle) you're using. Some styles don't trigger the appearance methods.

   see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517361/viewdidappear-and-viewdiddisappear-not-called-when-modalpresentationstyle-uimoda) for example.